# why doesn't this ruby code work

Tags: ruby

here's a practice question - Write a method that will take in a number of minutes, and returns a string that formats the number into `hours:minutes`.

```
def time_conversion(minutes)
    hours = minutes / 60
    mins = minutes % 60
    time = hours + ":" + mins
    return time
end
```

the following are tests to see if this works. if they return true then it means my code works correctly.

```
puts('time_conversion(15) == "0:15": ' + (time_conversion(15) == '0:15').to_s)
puts('time_conversion(150) == "2:30": ' + (time_conversion(150) == '2:30').to_s)
puts('time_conversion(360) == "6:00": ' + (time_conversion(360) == '6:00').to_s)
```

sometimes i get true for the first two tests but the third test line shows false even though the code will print out exactly the required.

other times I get the following error:

String can't be coerced into Fixnum (repl):4:in `+' (repl):4:in`time_conversion' (repl):1:in `initialize'

please assist.

Comment: You can't add a number to a string. Run `irb` and enter `5 + 'foo'`, and you'll get the same error. Try `time = hours.to_s + ':' + mins.to_s` in your `time_conversion` function. Or even just  replace the entire function contents with `return "#{minutes/60}:#{minutes % 60}"`

Comment: wow. that did the trick. I haven't come across using the hashes, but that's interesting. I suppose that allows me to remove the mins and hours variable

Comment: Yes you could remove those variables. You should look up "ruby string formatting" if you want to have leading zeroes in your minutes, like `6:05`. Your `time_conversion` won't create `6:00`. It will create `6:0`.

Comment: aahhh yeaa. I need to add the leading zero if the minutes were less than 10. (as a string)

but this is great. I'm loving all this. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error mainly refers to this line
`time = hours + ":" + mins`

`hours` & `mins` are `Fixnum`, whereas ":" is `String`
As the error message indicates, "String can't be coerced into Fixnum".

You could either do `time = hours.to_s + ":" + minutes.to_s` or `time = "#{hours}:#{minutes}"`.

Comment: yup, lurker pointed me to the same. I like the final suggestion there. it's nice and concise
thanks!

Comment: thanks for the upvote,, actually my first ans on stackoverflow!

Comment: that's cool. see you on the other side when I'm up and running myself

Answer (score 0):

Because `Fixnum#+` takes a `Numeral` argument, not a `String`.

Comment: my first question here and I got a super fast reply. thank you!